# normalize pandas data into one to many relation

Tags: pandas

My data frame has a column with comma delimited values saved as a single column.

```
from StringIO import StringIO

myst="""india | 905034 | 19:44 | cricket, hockey  
USA | 905094  | 19:33 | swimming, running, tennis, football
Russia |  905154 |   21:56 | basketball

"""
u_cols=['country', 'index', 'current_tm', 'sports']

myf = StringIO(myst)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep='|', names = u_cols)
```

Is it possible to break up the cells into several rows like this...

```
india cricket
india hockey
USA swimming
USA running
USA tennis
USA football
Russia basketball
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.split`, followed by a `apply(pd.Series).stack()` (the `apply(pd.Series)` makes different columns of the elements, `stack` is for turning this to rows):

```
In [34]: df = df.set_index('country')

In [36]: s = df['sports'].str.split(',').apply(pd.Series).stack()

In [37]: s
Out[37]:
country
india    0        cricket
         1       hockey
USA      0       swimming
         1        running
         2         tennis
         3       football
Russia   0     basketball
dtype: object
```

Then cleaning up a little bit further:

```
In [38]: s.reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[38]:
   country            0
0   india       cricket
1   india      hockey
2     USA      swimming
3     USA       running
4     USA        tennis
5     USA      football
6  Russia    basketball
```

Note, with recent pandas, you can replace the `.apply(pd.Series)` with `expand=True` in str.split: `df['sports'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()`

Comment: Is it possible to merge the columns like index and current_tm for respective country?

Comment: Yes, certainly. You can use merge: `pd.merge(res, df, on='country')` (assuming `res` is the result of above, and `df` has still the country column)

Comment: For some reason on clause did not work. So I tried right_index=True, left_index=True) and it gave the correct results. Thanks.